# can I use a multiprocessing pool to work on procedures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My understanding is that multiprocessing pools allows for multiple CPU usage when using functions. Such that something is returned:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

How would I preform a procedure which similarly maximises CPU usage.

I expected the following to work, but it did nothing.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    textfile.write(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
    textfile.close()
```

what can be done to maximise CPU usage when writing to text files?

Comment: What do you mean? Writing to a file is an IO-bound, not CPU-bound task. Multiprocessing will only make it slower probably.

Comment: and do you want them to write to different files or the same file? One is a breeze, the other a nightmare.

Comment: Is there any other way to improve the efficient of writing large quantities of information to a text file?

Comment: Use multi-threading to create the string to write to the file, then do the write at the end (not simultaneously).

Comment: Maybe I could have better asked this question. I have an iterator whose content I want to write to a text file, the size of which is very large.

Comment: Use multi-threading to create single joined string from your iterator, then write to file when finished threads.

Comment: I fear creating a string and writing at all at once would use too much memory throwing an erro